# How do I access the name of the city nested in this api response?

Tags: json, reactjs, object

I request data with axios.get(...), successful get the return as nested objects. I can access the data.message, data.cnt, data.cod but I can't access the properties of the "city". kept getting undefine or typeerror.

I want to access the properties of the city object nested within the response data. like this "data.city.name" but errors.

```
{
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0.0051,
  "cnt": 40,
  "list": [
    {
      "dt": 1545318000,
      "main": {
        "temp": 282.74,
        "temp_min": 282.167,
        "temp_max": 282.74,
        "pressure": 1012.86,
        "sea_level": 1020.54,
        "grnd_level": 1012.86,
        "humidity": 84,
        "temp_kf": 0.57
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 500,
          "main": "Rain",
          "description": "light rain",
          "icon": "10d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": { "all": 44 },
      "wind": { "speed": 5.67, "deg": 243.503 },
      "rain": { "3h": 0.25 },
      "sys": { "pod": "d" },
      "dt_txt": "2018-12-20 15:00:00"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1545739200,
      "main": {
        "temp": 282.628,
        "temp_min": 282.628,
        "temp_max": 282.628,
        "pressure": 1037.58,
        "sea_level": 1045.29,
        "grnd_level": 1037.58,
        "humidity": 100,
        "temp_kf": 0
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 500,
          "main": "Rain",
          "description": "light rain",
          "icon": "10d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": { "all": 76 },
      "wind": { "speed": 2.02, "deg": 212.503 },
      "rain": { "3h": 0.13 },
      "sys": { "pod": "d" },
      "dt_txt": "2018-12-25 12:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "city": {
    "id": 2643743,
    "name": "London",
    "coord": { "lat": 51.5073, "lon": -0.1277 },
    "country": "GB",
    "population": 1000000
  }
}
```

Comment: I opened a new file and clear all the quotation marks in the keys of the obj and when I access it like that with .js extension it works but how to access it from the response object in my project?

Comment: Can you post the code that accesses the object. I feel like something is happening there and not with the object, because it checks out as a valid object. If you can access one object key you should be able to access all. Try doing a console.log(typeof data) to make sure it's Object.

Comment: import React from "react";

const WeatherDisplay = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2>Message: {data.message}</h2>
      <p>Code: {data.cod}</p>
      <p>CNT: {data.cnt}</p>
      <h2>City Properties</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WeatherDisplay;

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.parse();

Example:

```
var data = JSON.parse(yourJSONObject)
console.log(data.city.name)
```

Comment: JSON.parse didn't work, my project is a React Component

Answer (score 1):

May not full represent what you need, but this should show how to set a default state, fetch your results, and then pass them into components. Your object is fine, I feel like you might be trying to access it before Axios completes.

```
export class DataView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        data: {}
      };
      this.defaultState = {
         // default properties of state 
      };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData = () => {
        await axios.get( ${apiEndpoint}${inputCity}&appid=${apiKey} )
        .then( data => {
            this.setState({
              data,
              ...this.defaultState,
              isLoading: false
            });
        });
    };


    render() {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          {this.state.isLoading ? ( // Check if it's still loading and load nothing if true
            <Fragment />
          ) : (
            <Component withProps={this.state.data}></Component> // Data can be accessed if isLoading: false
          )}
        </Fragment>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: sorry, didn't work, I tried with pure fetch method, exactly same result...wonder what could it be.

Comment: I know with fetch you I have to do fetch('whateverURL').then(res => res.json()).then(data => this.setState({res})

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting data.message, then you must get the city name with data.city.name

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some errors in your code because i can access the data and the json is also valid too.

try to console.log() the response and see what's going on.

Comment: async getData() {
    const { inputCity } = this.state;
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `${apiEndpoint}${inputCity}&appid=${apiKey}`
    );
    this.setState({ data });
    console.log(this.state.data);
  }

Answer (score 0):

[Seems to work fine with data.city.name](https://codepen.io/joshuakelly/pen/wRgmrx)

```
const data = {
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0.0051,
  "cnt": 40,
  "list": [
    {
      "dt": 1545318000,
      "main": {
        "temp": 282.74,
        "temp_min": 282.167,
        "temp_max": 282.74,
        "pressure": 1012.86,
        "sea_level": 1020.54,
        "grnd_level": 1012.86,
        "humidity": 84,
        "temp_kf": 0.57
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 500,
          "main": "Rain",
          "description": "light rain",
          "icon": "10d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": { "all": 44 },
      "wind": { "speed": 5.67, "deg": 243.503 },
      "rain": { "3h": 0.25 },
      "sys": { "pod": "d" },
      "dt_txt": "2018-12-20 15:00:00"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1545739200,
      "main": {
        "temp": 282.628,
        "temp_min": 282.628,
        "temp_max": 282.628,
        "pressure": 1037.58,
        "sea_level": 1045.29,
        "grnd_level": 1037.58,
        "humidity": 100,
        "temp_kf": 0
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 500,
          "main": "Rain",
          "description": "light rain",
          "icon": "10d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": { "all": 76 },
      "wind": { "speed": 2.02, "deg": 212.503 },
      "rain": { "3h": 0.13 },
      "sys": { "pod": "d" },
      "dt_txt": "2018-12-25 12:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "city": {
    "id": 2643743,
    "name": "London",
    "coord": { "lat": 51.5073, "lon": -0.1277 },
    "country": "GB",
    "population": 1000000
  }
}

document.write(data.city.name);

getData = async () => {
  const { inputCity } = this.state;

  try {
    const data = await axios.get(${apiEndpoint}${inputCity}&appid=${apiKey});
    this.setState({ data });
    console.log(this.state.data);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: async getData() {
    const { inputCity } = this.state;
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `${apiEndpoint}${inputCity}&appid=${apiKey}`
    );
    this.setState({ data });
    console.log(this.state.data);
  }

Comment: The above code is how I get the data and console.logging is fine...I just couldn't access the city properties like data.city.name while I can access data.message which returns the value in number.

Comment: You are trying to load details into the DOM before the request completes. Set an initial state in your component for something like isLoading: true and render your HTML after the .get completes by setting a setState({data, isLoading: false})

Comment: @MyanmarGospelSermons I've updated my answer with a potential call method. You need to wait until the promise resolves from axios until the data is available to update your state.

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to take the input value (city name) and added that to my apiEndpoint to search for the relevant data, so I think there couldn't be a default. I am overwhelmed already.